# Code generation from jinja2 ast

Tags: parsing, templates, jinja2, abstract-syntax-tree

Let's say I have a jinja template

```
<style>
p{
    font-family : 'Times New Roman',Times,serif;
    font-size:15px;
}
</style>

<p>------- Information -------- </p>

{% set p1 = getP1('dataset') %}

<table style='width:100%'>
<tr>
    <th>Information</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>{{p1.a}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>{{p1.b}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td>{{p1.c}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I can parse the code with jinja2 to the jinja2 Template, where the code is the string which I pasted above.

```
In [58]: from jinja2 import Environment

In [59]: env = Environment()

In [60]: m = env.parse(code)

In [61]: m
Out[61]: Template(body=[Output(nodes=[TemplateData(data=u"\n<style>\np{\n\tfont-family : 'Times New Roman',Times,serif;\n\tfont-size:15px;\n}\n</style>\n\n<p>------- Information -------- </p>\n\n")]), Assign(target=Name(name='p1', ctx='store'), node=Call(node=Name(name='getP1', ctx='load'), args=[Const(value=u'dataset')], kwargs=[], dyn_args=None, dyn_kwargs=None)), Output(nodes=[TemplateData(data=u"\n\n<table style='width:100%'>\n\t<tr>\n\t\t<th>Information</th>\n\t</tr>\n\t<tr>\n\t\t<td>A</td>\n\t\t<td>"), Getattr(node=Name(name='p1', ctx='load'), attr='a', ctx='load'), TemplateData(data=u'</td>\n\t</tr>\n\t<tr>\n\t\t<td>B</td>\n\t\t<td>'), Getattr(node=Name(name='p1', ctx='load'), attr='b', ctx='load'), TemplateData(data=u'</td>\n\t</tr>\n\t<tr>\n\t\t<td>C</td>\n\t\t<td>'), Getattr(node=Name(name='p1', ctx='load'), attr='c', ctx='load'), TemplateData(data=u'</td>\n\t</tr>\n</table>')])])
```

How can I convert back the template to the code?

In the case of python code, we have packages like [astor](https://astor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
According to this [issue](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/719), jinja2 doesn't support that functionality ! so How can I write a code to do that?